# cross thread event azure c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using the BlobTransfer class and ctlTransfer control from Azure.  I am running a BackgroundWorker to search for files and then download them.  I had to invoke the part where the ctlTransfer control gets added to the flowLayoutPanel.  They show up but the progress doesn't change.  I think it has to do with the ProgressChanged event being added from the BackgroundWorker thread.

```
blobTransfer.TransferProgressChanged += new EventHandler<BlobTransfer.BlobTransferProgressChangedEventArgs>(blobTransfer_TransferProgressChanged);
```

This is in the ctlTransfer() constructor